# Alphashapes in 3d point cloud of trees

Tags: python, geometry, point-clouds, convex-hull, lidar

I need help finding the smallest enclosing volume of the crown of a tree (forest tree) and the vertices of the points that compose that volume. This can be solved by finding an alpha shape (a concave hull) for that tree. I don't know c++ so CGAL and PCL are out of question. Is there a handy way to do this in python?

I have used ConvexHull from scipy

```py
dataframe = pd.read_csv(base + direct + '\\' + file)
      #dataframe = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\jpps_\\Documents\\Projeto_Novo\\Cylinders_Eucaliptos_Pinheiros_Veg_Acima_15m\\cilnr19.0.csv')
        trees= dataframe[(dataframe['raw_classification']!=30) & (dataframe['intensity']!=64)][['X','Y','Z','intensity']].reset_index(drop=True)
        points = np.array(trees[['X','Y','Z']].values)            
        hull = ConvexHull(points)
        indices = hull.vertices
        vertices = points[indices]
        vert_df = pd.DataFrame(vertices,columns = ['X','Y','Z'])
```

I was hoping there is a similar procedure, but that will render me an alpha shape.

point cloud img:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, have a look at [Alpha Shape Toolbox](https://pypi.org/project/alphashape/) at `pypi.org`:

---

[image: Fig]

          

<sup>Plate Carree Projection</sup>

---

Comment: I have looked into it, and it seems as though it works for 2D. For this point cloud I am working with (three dimensional) it does not. Is it also the case for you?

Comment: @PedroPinheiro: Ah, sorry. My oversight.